# chmod ugo+rwx Operation not permited

Tags: linux, chmod

I am trying to change access rights on `tomcat-users.xml` file under Linux Mint by:

```sh
chmod ugo+rwx tomcat-users.xml
```

But I'm receiving this error message:

```sh
Operation not permitted
```

`tomcat-users.xml` has the following permissions and attributes:

```sh
$ ls -la tomcat-users.xml
-rw-r-r-- 1 root root tomcat-users.xml

$ lsattr tomcat-users.xml 
---------------e--- tomcat-users.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la tomcat-users.xml` and `whoami` and `lsattr tomcat-users.xml`? Did you try `chmod 0777 tomcat-users.xml`? Does `sudo chmod 0777 tomcat-users.xml` work?

Comment: ls -la tomcat-users.xml   give me -rw-r-r-- 1 root root  tomcat-users.xml .         lsattr tomcat-users.xml    give  ---------------e--- tomcat-users.xml

Comment: After sudo chmod 0777 tomcat-users.xml     Operation not permitted

Comment: File is owned by `root` and group `root`. To be able to change its permissions you need to be `root` or have a way to execute the command as `root` (hence the `sudo` option). If you can't become `root` nor elevate your privileges using `sudo` or `su`, you won't be able to change the file's permissions. One last guess: maybe the filesystem where the file is located is in `read-only` mode.

Comment: I entered as root and changed access rights successfully! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This command is correct is all ways but if there is an issue the, probably you would have been changing permissions of a file from a user(except root) who is not owner of the file.
Or if the owner is root then switch to it.
Or run the command from root.

And still does not work then go for

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx tomcat-users.xml
```

Comment: `g=rxx` is not a valid option.